# Android numeric password input in an EditText Field

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, passwords, numeric

Can someone show me the coding for setting an edittext field to accept numeric values only(Password that the user has to type in), and asimple example of how would the coding be.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should be add the marked (`android:inputType="numberPassword"`):
For example:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>
```

Comment: and how do i set the desired password i want? where would i add that coding?

Comment: you should add this code in your xml file, you should add the marked 'android:inputType="numberPassword" ' in your EditText .

Answer (score 0):

We can use these property in EditText xml.

`android:inputType="numberPassword"
 android:digits="0123456789."`

Comment: Should be android:digits